# Conflict between 2 websockets

Tags: javascript, api, websocket, cryptocurrency

I've been trying to create a script which shows Bitcoin and Ethereum price according to users preference. So if an user clicks on bitcoin button it shows bitcoin price and when user clicks on Ethereum button it shows Ethereum.

Everything kind of works but when you click on Bitcoin button and then on Ethereum button it creates a conflict and keeps switching between Bitcoin and Ethereum price.

I have tried to use

pricesWs1.close(); and pricesWs.close(); but it completely closes 1 websocket and you can't swap between the prices.

Javascript

```
const pricesWs = new WebSocket('wss://ws.coincap.io/prices?assets=bitcoin')
 const pricesWs1 = new WebSocket('wss://ws.coincap.io/prices?assets=ethereum')  
 
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.buttonbtc').click(function(e) {  

pricesWs.onmessage = function (msg) {

        var str = msg.data                                      
    var matches = str.match (/\b\d+(?:.\d+)?/);
    var finalprice = parseFloat(matches);
     document.getElementById("btc").innerHTML = finalprice;
     
}

   });
});

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.buttoneth').click(function(e) {  
    
pricesWs1.onmessage = function (msgg) {
    
    var str = msgg.data                                      
    var matches = str.match (/\b\d+(?:.\d+)?/);
    var finalprice = parseFloat(matches);
    document.getElementById("btc").innerHTML = finalprice;
}

   });
});
```

[LIVE DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/s9rv1agu/](https://jsfiddle.net/s9rv1agu/)

Comment: Is creating 2 websockets your only option? If not Coincap api allows you to provide 2 parameters. `wss://ws.coincap.io/prices?assets=bitcoin,ethereum`. You can save the result in a hash map and only change between the selected asset. The websocket will still listen to both price sin the background

Comment: Yes it's possible to provide multiple parameters. The problem is that I have no idea how to separate them one by one and can't find information on the coincap api documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you're getting constant response messages from the coinbase server.
You can prevent the text display from being updated onmessage unless the socket that sent it matches the last clicked button.

In this case I stored the value of the last clicked button in a variable named cp and only update the display on message if it was sent by the corresponding socket.

Code:

```
    const pricesWs = new WebSocket('wss://ws.coincap.io/prices?assets=bitcoin')
     const pricesWs1 = new WebSocket('wss://ws.coincap.io/prices?assets=ethereum');
     
     var cp = -1;//current_price
     
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.buttonbtc').click(function(e) {  
    
     cp = 0;
     document.getElementById("btc").innerHTML = "pending...";
    pricesWs.onmessage = function (msg) {
    
         if(cp == 0) {
            var str = msg.data                                      
        var matches = str.match (/\b\d+(?:.\d+)?/);
        var finalprice = parseFloat(matches);
         document.getElementById("btc").innerHTML = finalprice;
    }
         
    }
    
       });
    });
    
    
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.buttoneth').click(function(e) {  
        
    cp = 1;
    document.getElementById("btc").innerHTML = "pending...";
    pricesWs1.onmessage = function (msgg) {
        if(cp == 1) {
        var str = msgg.data                                      
        var matches = str.match (/\b\d+(?:.\d+)?/);
        var finalprice = parseFloat(matches);
    
        document.getElementById("btc").innerHTML = finalprice;
        }
    }
    
       });
    });
```

If you however also want to stop the root cause of the problem(the constant messages being sent by the server) you will need to iniate the socket connection and close the connection after a message (or possibly some configuration with coinbase which will only send back 1 message).

```
var pricesWs;
var pricesWs1;

const wlist = ['wss://ws.coincap.io/prices?assets=bitcoin',
             'wss://ws.coincap.io/prices?assets=ethereum'];
 
 var cp = -1;//current_price
 
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.buttonbtc').click(function(e) {  

 cp = 0;
 document.getElementById("btc").innerHTML = "pending...";
 pricesWs = new WebSocket(wlist[0]);
  pricesWs.onopen = function() {
pricesWs.onmessage = function (msg) {

     if(cp == 0) {
        var str = msg.data                                      
    var matches = str.match (/\b\d+(?:.\d+)?/);
    var finalprice = parseFloat(matches);
     document.getElementById("btc").innerHTML = finalprice;
}
     pricesWs.close();
}
}

   });
});


 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.buttoneth').click(function(e) {  
    
cp = 1;
document.getElementById("btc").innerHTML = "pending...";
 pricesWs1 = new WebSocket(wlist[1]);
 pricesWs1.onopen = function() {
pricesWs1.onmessage = function (msgg) {
    if(cp == 1) {
    var str = msgg.data                                      
    var matches = str.match (/\b\d+(?:.\d+)?/);
    var finalprice = parseFloat(matches);

    document.getElementById("btc").innerHTML = finalprice;
        }
    pricesWs1.close();
    }
}

   });
});
```

an additional check can also be added to ensure the sockets are not in the process of being opened when a button is clicked